# How can group multi data array to 1 array

Tags: javascript

[i have a list data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caBmo.png)

i expected that:

```
[
    {
      "country_code": "US",
      "data": [3,3,3,3]
    },
    {
      "country_code": "VN",
      "data": [1,2,3,5]
    }
  ]
```

I tried loop for each array but result not is expect. Anyone help me. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite obviously. No need stupid loops. Here you go:

```
var data = [
    {
        time: 1,
        country:
        [
            { country_code: 'US', order_count: 11 },
            { country_code: 'CN', order_count: 21 },
            { country_code: 'VN', order_count: 31 }
        ]
    },
    {
        time: 2,
        country:
        [
            { country_code: 'US', order_count: 12 },
            { country_code: 'CN', order_count: 22 },
            { country_code: 'VN', order_count: 32 }
        ]
    },
    {
        time: 3,
        country:
        [
            { country_code: 'US', order_count: 13 },
            { country_code: 'CN', order_count: 23 },
            { country_code: 'VN', order_count: 33 }
        ]
    }
]

// suppose data[0] contains all country codes
const all_country_codes = (data) => 
    data[0].country.map(c => c.country_code); 

const get_order_count = (data, code) => 
    data.country.filter(d => d.country_code == code)[0].order_count;

const get_all_order_counts = (data, code) => 
    data.map(d => get_order_count(d, code))

const make_node = (data, code) => 
    ({ country_code:code, data:get_all_order_counts(data, code) })

const output = (data) => 
    all_country_codes(data).map(code => make_node(data, code));

console.log(output(data));
```

Output:

```
[
  { country_code: 'US', data: [ 11, 12, 13 ] },
  { country_code: 'CN', data: [ 21, 22, 23 ] },
  { country_code: 'VN', data: [ 31, 32, 33 ] }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `array.reduce()` and `array.forEach()` as:

```js
const data = [
    {
        time: 1,
        country:
        [
            { country_code: 'US', order_count: 11 },
            { country_code: 'CN', order_count: 21 },
            { country_code: 'VN', order_count: 31 }
        ]
    },
    {
        time: 2,
        country:
        [
            { country_code: 'US', order_count: 12 },
            { country_code: 'CN', order_count: 22 },
            { country_code: 'VN', order_count: 32 }
        ]
    },
    {
        time: 3,
        country:
        [
            { country_code: 'US', order_count: 13 },
            { country_code: 'CN', order_count: 23 },
            { country_code: 'VN', order_count: 33 }
        ]
    }
]

const mappedData = data.reduce((mdAcc, obj) => {
   obj.country.forEach((country) => {
      let obj = mdAcc.find((md) => md.country_code === country.country_code);
      if (!obj) {
        mdAcc.push({country_code: country.country_code, data: [country.order_count]});
      } else {
         obj.data.push(country.order_count);
      }
   })

   return mdAcc;
}, []);
```